# Connection refused with two microservices

Tags: microservices, amazon-ecs

I am getting ECONREFUSED error, it seems establish a connection with another service was refused and something is blocking the request.
I am using random token and using the same token for all the microservices deployed in different AWS region

***{"message":"","name":"AggregateError","stack":"AggregateError: \n    at Function.AxiosError.from (/var/perth/node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:89:14)\n    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (/var/perth/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:577:25)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:531:35)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)\n    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers. (/var/perth/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:14:24)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)\n    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)\n    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)\n    at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"adapter":["xhr","http"],"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":30000,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","X-Token":"123456789","User-Agent":"perth-Api-Gateway","Content-Type":"application/json","X-perth-Organization-Id":"null","X-perth-USER":"null","X-perth-User-Id":"null","X-perth-App-Id":"null","X-perth-Cron":"null","Content-Length":"2","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, compress, deflate, br"},"url":"http://apisyd.perth.io:4444/login","method":"get","data":"{}"},"code":"ECONNREFUSED","status":null}***

Steps taken
-I have ensured that the endpoint address and port specified in the code are accurate and accessible
-I have confirmed that there aren't any firewall settings or network restrictions preventing the connection at application level
-I have confirmed that the service I am trying to connect to is operational and accepting connections

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example